# How to copy two columns from one Excel file to a new one with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to copy 2 columns from Excel file 'Input.xlsx' to a new Excel file 'Output.xlsx'. I tried the following code using Pandas, but in the 'Output.xlsx' file data turn out written all in the first row, I do not have 2 columns of data anymore. Can you help me fixing the code?
Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd
document1 = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\Input.xlsx')
sheets=document1.sheet_names
appended_data=[]
df1=pd.read_excel(document1, sheets, usecols=[' Speed of sound (c) [m/s]',' Outlet Temperature (T out) [°C]'])
appended_data.append(df1)
appended_data=pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
appended_data.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Note, you don't need to use `sheets=document1.sheet_names`, then `sheets` in `read_excel`. Just use `sheet_name=None`.

Comment: Noted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file:

```py
import pandas as pd

fn = 'C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\Input.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(fn, usecols=[' Speed of sound (c) [m/s]',' Outlet Temperature (T out) [°C]'])
df.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)
```

For multiple files:

```py
import pandas as pd

fns = ['Input1.xlsx', 'Input2.xlsx']
column_names = [' Speed of sound (c) [m/s]',' Outlet Temperature (T out) [°C]']

input_dfs = []
for fn in fns:
    input_df = pd.read_excel(fn, usecols=column_names)
    input_dfs.append(input_df)
output_df = pd.concat(input_dfs)
output_df.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: `df1` is probably a dict of DataFrames actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works perfectly! Now I need to iterate this code over multiple input excel files (Input1.xlsx, Input2.xlsx ecc) and copy two columns from each file into the same Excel file Output.xlsx ( either in the same sheet or in different sheets, it doesn't matter)..Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could loop over your files, create one dataframe for each file, and finally concatenate them into a single dataframe. I've updated my solution above.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! However I need to put the columns copied from different files one beside the other, not one under the other, as concat does...I tried with df.merge(), but it doesn't work. What else could I try?